# Does Apache Storm have an HTTP API?

Tags: apache-storm

I would like to just HTTP POST events into a spout. Do I need to set up a web server myself, or would that be redundant? All of the tutorials that I have seen so far assume that an application will be fetching (or even just generating) the data itself and passing it to `emit-spout!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm used a pull based model in `Spouts.nextTuple()`. Thus, it might be best to have a buffer in between -- a WebServer takes HTTP POST requests and writes into that buffer. A Spout can pull the date from the buffer.

Comment: Sounds like the Storm people don't want an HTTP server cluttering up their project. I'm sure they have good reasons, SRP? I will probably always want an HTTP interface to Storm, but I suppose that that doesn't apply to everyone. Open source opportunity :p

Comment: I would put it differently: it's a question of current system designed and effort to change it. But Storm community is always happy to start a discussion about new ideas and adaption :) dev@storm.apache.org